# jq ajax why xdebug-var-dump

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I run sample ajax code:

```
var postFunc = function() {
        $.ajax({
            type   : "POST",
            data   : {
                post_func_resp: true
            },
            url    : ajaxurl,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error  : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
            }
        })
    };
    postFunc();
```

in my php just

```
if(isset($_POST)) {
echo 'some response';
}
```

and i got some debug data(or something) with my response:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
<b>array</b> <i>(size=0)</i>
<i><font color='#888a85'>empty</font></i>
</pre>some response
```

what this means? how can i avoid this appended data?

UPD: if disable xdebug i got empty array before data:

```
array(0) {

}some data
```

Comment: I suspect you have `XDEBUG_SESSION` in your cookies, so Xdebug is running when you make the AJAX call.

Comment: yeah, right, but its strange. i dnt expect that

Comment: You must have a call to `var_dump()` in your script somewhere.